# How to do Backing in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, zend-framework

I am using ZF1.12. I am new in zend framework.

I want same backing feature in zend framework as in cake php.

Please suggest me what naming convention I should use in zend framework to generate automatic project. How to run backing.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zftool for code generation
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html

Comment: It generates empty controller and model. But in cake we get add, edit delete feature. Just we work on database and all is done. how we can do same in zendframewrk.

Comment: Zend Framework is not hmm... this kind of framework. You can generate the methods also with zftool.